# Return a parameter in Google App Script callback

Tags: asp.net, google-apps-script, callback

The following example code successfully performs a callback to the Google App Script:

```
var SCRIPT_ID = "1eC5VsM2vkJXa9slM40MTKTlfARGAGyK1myMCU3AB_-Ox_jGxQaoPM8P2";

function getURL() { return getCallbackURL('testCallback'); }

function getCallbackURL(callback) {
  var state = ScriptApp.newStateToken().withTimeout(3600).withMethod(callback).createToken();
  return 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/'+SCRIPT_ID+'/usercallback?state='+state;
}

function doGet(e){ return HtmlService.createTemplate(" <div><p><a href='<?=getURL()?>' id='start-auth'><?=getURL()?></a></p></div>").evaluate()); }

function testCallback(e){
  Logger.log('myVariable1= ' + e.parameter.myVariable1); // this doesn't work
  Logger.log('myVariable2= ' + e.parameter.myVariable2); // this doesn't work
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Success. You can close this window. !</b>')
}
```

However I need to return a variable to the "testCallback" method as part of a HttpRepsonse redirect.  I've tried settings a cookie and also setting a header variable in my asp.net C# application as follow:

```
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("myVariable1");
            cookie.Value = "someValue1";
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            Response.AddHeader("myVariable2", "someValue2");
            Response.Redirect(applicationCallbackUri, true);
```

but it's not clear whether the header or cookie variables are available to Google's callback method:

```
function testCallback(e){
  Logger.log('myVariable1= ' + e.parameter.myVariable1);
  Logger.log('myVariable2= ' + e.parameter.myVariable2);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Success. You can close this window. 
!</b>')
}
```

I've also tried using the .WithArguments method when creating the a new state token, but I'm not sure if its possible for my asp.net application to update the state object's arguments as part of the redirect/return.

I've also tried appending the variable to the Google Callback URL, e.g.
    https://script.google.com/macros/d/1eC5VsM2vkJXa9slM40MTKTlfARGAGyK1myMCU3AB_-Ox_jGxQaoPM8P2?state=ADEpC8w0dL6mBVmDQHX3XcYcBP0JqQ5_etc&myVariable1=someValue1

However Google throws an "invalid state" error

Answer (score 0):

The event object passed to your `testCallback(e)` function cannot reference HTTP headers or cookies and appending arbitrary url variables to the redirect url won't work either (the authorization server that does the redirect will omit them to ensure security).

The only valid way to send state vars is using the `withArguments()` method. However, your `Logger.log()` calls won't work b/c the calls (to the `testCallback(e)` function) are asynchronous and they are not tracked in the editor. Instead, try enabling StackDriver Logging from the Apps Script Editor's View menu and replace those `Logger.log()` calls with `console.log()`. Your logs should then show up under StackDriver Logging in your Google API Console for the project.

Comment: I can set a parameter using the withArguments from the Google App Script, and see the same value in the callback.  But how does my asp.net application change this value?  Is there an algorithm for decoding the state string (within my asp.net page) so that I can modify the value, re-encode the state string just prior to the callback?

If not, what is the correct method for Google App Script to call an external service and extract a variable from the response (in a callback)

Comment: Looking at the oAuth example, this also uses the callback mechanism.  In here you can see that callback has access to variables such as 'code' and 'error'.  I'm wondering how that is being achieved?

Service_.prototype.handleCallback = function(callbackRequest) {
var code = callbackRequest.parameter.code;
var error = callbackRequest.parameter.error;

Comment: You cannot change the value nor decode the state string. That would defeat the purpose of having an OAuth2 flow in the first place - a secure reliable method to authenticate users and authorize applications on their behalf. You should check out this video (linked below) it will explain the process behind oauth2 flows better than I can: https://youtu.be/CPbvxxslDTU

Comment: :) Maybe it would help if I explained the actual use-case. I'm trying to achieve a double-hop authentication.  We have a number of end-user applications that need to use oAuth but without those applications knowing the clientId/secret.  Our web server has the clientId/secret, and we require the web server to handle the oAuth authentication, then pass back the bearer token to the calling apps, in this example the Google App Script.

Comment: You can only pass custom params to the /usercallback endpoint via the encoded state url variable, so you may be out of luck. If all you want to do is avoid exposing the client id and secret then you may want to consider converting your GAS applications to add-ons or web apps (end-users cannot access the underlying code in an GAS add-on or web-app so its safe to store your client-id and secret as hard-coded values).